# Convert Flex Builder 3 project to Flash Builder 4

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flexbuilder, flex4, gumbo

I just upgraded to Flash Builder 4 (beta 2) from Flex Builder 3 which I have been using since it came out. Problem: All the projects that were in my workspace from Flex Builder 3 did not carry over into Flash Builder 4 (e.g. in the "Flex Navigator" view if FB3). Flash Builder 4 now uses the .FXP format to manage projects, but Flex Builder 3 did not. Is there an easy way to get all my projects back into Flash Builder 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use File->Import->Other
In the dialog, select General->Existing Projects into Workspace
Point the root directory to your workspace, check all the projects you want to import and that's it.
Worked just fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Sharvey's answer was correct, but I also wanted to correct something from the original question, the part about .fxp files.  Flash Builder 4 has not changed the format in which it stores projects; it still stores them as a directory with a .project file, a .actionScriptProperties file, and so on, just as Flex Builder 3 did.  Where .fxp files come in is, they provide an easy way to package up a project into a single file and share it -- not only with other Flash Builder users, but also with users of Catalyst.

Catalyst is different from Flash Builder: .fxp files are its "native" format.  So, suppose a designer created a project in Catalyst; you, the developer, could then import that .fxp file into Flash Builder using the "import FXP" command.  When you do that, it unpacks the fxp into a traditional project format on disk.

Hope this helps clarify things!  - Mike Morearty, Flash Builder team